# Multiple Errors in screen

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to display error in toolbar without using [PXProcessButton] and the delegate? I've overridden a Process Button in acumatica, but before it executes I have underlying codes to check a condition and fire an error if it find any.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of valid scenario where you have a `PXProcessButton` without a `PXProcessing` or `PXFilteredProcessing` data view. I would expect a `PXButton` to be used when there is no `PXProcessing` data view instead of a `PXProcessButton`.

With a `PXProcessing` view in the process screen you would do:

```
PXProcessing<DAC>.SetError(new PXException("Test));
```

---

There is no method that I know of that allows to directly set an error in the toolbar. You'll notice that these error are tied with a `PXLongOperation`. In the main toolbar you'll see the hourglass icon of the long operation and it can change to a success or error icon.

Process action does this but also Save action amongst others. Unless you require a long operation I would advise to avoid displaying error in the main toolbar because it's not a behavior found in the base Acumatica product.

That said you can replicate that functionality pretty much everywhere by throwing a `PXException`from within a `PXLongOperation` inside an `PXAction` event handler like this:

```
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    public PXAction<SOOrder> test;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test")]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Test(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate {
        throw new PXException("Test");
      });

      return adapter.Get();
    }
  }
```

[image]